# How to populate a dropdown box with "value" parameter for each option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to populate a dropdown box based on the selection of a different drop down box:

```js
ps4models = new Array("Select My Model", "PS4 (Release Model)", "PS4 Slim", "PS4 Pro");
xboxonemodels = new Array("Select My Model", "Xbox One (Release Model)", "Xbox One Slim", "Xbox One Scorpio");

populateSelect();

$(function() {
  $('#console').change(function() {
    populateSelect();
  });
});

function populateSelect() {
  console = $('#console').val();
  $('#model').html('');

  if (console == 'ps4') {
    ps4models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
    });
  }

  if (console == 'xboxone') {
    xboxonemodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="console">
  <option value="selectconsole">Select My Console</option>
  <option value="ps4">PS4</option>
  <option value="xboxone">Xbox One</option>
</select>
<select id="model"></select>
```

This populates the second dropdown box, but it does it without adding the "value" parameter. How would I adapt the code to create a "value" parameter with each option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('#model').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
```

Do:

```
$('#model').append($('<option>').val(t).text(t));
```

NB: This is more the jQuery way of appending options, and will escape special characters like `"` and `&` automatically.

Comment: Thank you! Is it ok to have a value with spaces? I assumed it would have to be done with incremental numbers?

Comment: Value attribute can be any string. But be aware it will be a string, even if you set it to a number. It can have spaces.

Comment: What about special characters? I have brackets in some of them

Comment: Brackets are no problem. Did you try it? Special characters like double quote, greater-than, ...etc will be escaped automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing something, but to append options with values, you append options, just like you are, with values, just like you did in the HTML snippet that has values:

```
      $('#model').append('<option value="' + t + '">' + t + '</option>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Adrian. I have used trincot's example, but I'm sure yours was fine too

Answer (score 0):

In plain old JavaScript, you can create an Option element like so:

```
var modelSelect = document.getElementById('model');
var selectOption = document.createElement('option');

selectOption.text = 'Select My Model';
selectOption.value = 'Select My Model';

modelSelect.add(selectOption);
```

You can create a jQuery plugin to handle populating the dropdowns for you. All you need to do is pass in the data. It can be either an array or an object.

You can also specify a key and text field, if each item in the array is an object.

Also, you should create a data object and access the different values by keys. This will allow you to loop over the data easily.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.populateDropdown = function(data, removePrevious, value, text) {
    text = text || value;
    if (removePrevious === true) {
      this.find('option').remove();
    }
    if ($.isArray(data)) {
      this.append(data.map(function(item) {
        let value = $.isPlainObject(item) ? item[value] : item;
        let text = $.isPlainObject(item) ? item[text] : item;
        return $('<option>').val(value).text(text);
      }));
    } else {
      this.append(Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
        return $('<option>').val(key).text(data[key][value]);
      }));
    }
    return this;
  }
})(jQuery)

var viewData = {
  ps4models: {
    text: 'PS4',
    value: ["Select My Model", "PS4 (Release Model)", "PS4 Slim", "PS4 Pro"]
  },
  xboxonemodels: {
    text: 'Xbox One',
    value: ["Select My Model", "Xbox One (Release Model)", "Xbox One Slim", "Xbox One Scorpio"]
  }
};

$('#console')
  .append($('<option>').val('selectconsole').text('Select My Console'))
  .populateDropdown(viewData, false, 'text');

$(function() {
  $('#console').change(function(e) {
    $('#model').populateDropdown(viewData[e.target.value]['value'], true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="console"></select>
<select id="model"></select>
```